# Why isn't this form returning results?

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, forms

I have just started trying to learn PHP and MYSQL and have been following some tutorials for creating a webpage search engine, but have been experience an issue wherein when i submit the form the results aren't returned, i have no idea as to where the problem lies or where to try and troubleshoot it, so it thought it'll be worth a shot to post my problem here. Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks in advance.

**PHP**

```
<?php   

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","123")or die("Could not connect to Db");
    mysql_select_db("members") or die("Could not find db");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['submit'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $query = mysql_query("Select * FROM memberlist WHERE Fname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Lname LIKE '%$searchq%'  ") or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);


 if($count == 0){
    $output = "No results were found, sorry.";
}

else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $firstname = $row['Fname'];
        $lastname = $row['Lname'];
        $output .= "<div>".$firstname." ".$firstname."</div>";
    }
}
}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="searchfname" placeholder="Enter first name">
<input type="text" name="searchlname" placeholder="Enter last name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php print($output);?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (1) mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used. Find a tutorial that uses the newer PDO or mysqli functions, or you're going to be lost in future versions of PHP. PDO and mysqli will also allow you to use parameters, which will prevent SQL injection. (2) Where does it break? Does it say 'no results were found' or just outputs your else? If it says no results were found, try echoing out your query and putting it directly into a mysql client.

Comment: @Jack: Are the above listings in the same file or in different ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$_POST['submit']` to check if the form was submitted, but it does not hold all the form values.
You can access the separate form values by their respective name.

So use `$_POST['searchfname']` for the value in the first textbox and `$_POST['searchlname']` for the second.

Your code should read more like this;

```
$searchqf = $_POST['searchfname'];
$searchql = $_POST['searchlname'];
$searchqfreplace = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchqf);
$searchqlreplace = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchql);
$query = mysql_query("Select * FROM memberlist WHERE Fname LIKE '%$searchqf%' OR Lname LIKE '%$searchql%'  ") or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Notice that this way of composing queries is very insecure and vulnerable for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You're also asking for a way to troubleshoot. You probably want to look into [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but it seems i have more problems. http://pastebin.com/UadVCPEY

Comment: Check your capitals. You use Fname in your code, while the real column name is FName. So change it to `$row['FName']`. Also this is all very basic PHP/MySQL knowledge. You would probably learn a lot more from just experimenting and follow some good tutorials.

Comment: No problem, please don't forget to close this question and mark one of the answers as a solution to your problem if it helped you!

Comment: Thanks again, but before i close the q, do you know why i need to enter both fields before it'll query the db.? For instance if i enter "john" nothing happens but if i enter "john wilkinson" - only john wilkinson" will appear - as it should.

Comment: Because if you just enter one, it will probably produce an invalid query. You should check if the `$_POST['searchlname']` contains a value, and if it does include it in your query. Else leave out the OR part of the query all together.

Comment: I simply swapped out the OR for an AND, which is doing the trick. But the logic is troubling me, why wouldn't OR achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the $searchq variable to your submit button.
Change this line

```
$searchq = $_POST['submit'];
```

to

```
$searchq = $_POST['searchfname'];
```

or

```
$searchq = $_POST['searchlname'];
```

or both:

```
$searchq = $_POST['searchfname'].$_POST['searchlname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use $searchq = $_POST['submit']; since no value is being posted whose name is submit

you must use any of the following....

**$searchq = $_POST['searchfname'];**

**or**

**$searchq = $_POST['searchlname'];**

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are searching for 'submit' value instead of values from form.

Replace `$searchq = $_POST['submit'];` with:

```
$searchq = $_POST['searchfname'];
$searchq2 = $_POST['searchlname'];
```

and query:

```
Select * FROM memberlist WHERE Fname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Lname LIKE '%$searchq2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

either search with `searchfname` or with `searchlname` or both.

Secondly, modify like this 
after `$count = mysql_num_rows($query);`,

```
if($count == 0){
    $output = "No results were found, sorry.";
}
else{
    $output = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $firstname = $row['Fname'];
        $lastname = $row['Lname'];
        $output .= "<div>".$firstname." ".$firstname."</div>";
    }
```

Thirdly, Use `print $output` in the `Second page(where database is fetched)` and not in `First page(Page with FORM)`.

If you want to show result in the First page, use jQuery/Ajax function

Comment: DB is fetched on the same page.